# Semantic search .net library

Tags: c#, asp.net, content-management-system, semantics

I want to build a dynamic course content system based on existing materials (PDF,PPT,Word documents ...etc)

My basic requirement is the `semantic search` in these files to extract contents  .

i ask about .net library or API to use in my system .

Like [Kngine](http://www.kngine.com/),[WordNet](http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn),[Terrier](http://www.smartfp7.eu/content/gla-university-glasgow-uk-terrier-search-engine),[jatetoolkit](http://code.google.com/p/jatetoolkit/)

Comment: What is your Question?

Comment: ِAsking about `semantic search API for .net`

Comment: You have add a specific problem you have because in its current state your question is a poll which will pickup close votes...

Comment: I just ask if any one use  a .net library for this issue .

Comment: I once had requested wordnet data for my project [educational use] and i was able to use it. However, you can request for a commercial use and try it. It was useful to map related words.

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server 2012 has new features for semantic search in conjunction with Full-text search which was improved accordingly as well. It may or may not satisfy your requrements, but definitely deserve to be looked at.
Here is an example which you may start from: http://svenaelterman.wordpress.com/2012/04/14/step-by-step-enabling-semantic-search-on-sql-server-2012/

Comment: Thanks a lot but how can i use this feature in my .net application to search across files semantically  ??

Comment: First link shows sql setup, next step - quries. You may find examples hefe (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg492075.aspx) and here (http://dougbert.com/blog/post/More-sample-queries-for-Semantic-Search-in-SQL-Server-2012.aspx). You can use any method you like to execute these queries from your app (sqlconnection, dapper, nhibernate, etc)

Comment: The problem is that SQL Server returns a maximum of 10 rows.

Answer (score 2):

Look into Lucene.Net... A bit of a learning curve, but should do the trick quite nicely. I am currently moving to this platform and away from SQL 2012.

Answer (score 1):

I know that the [commercial dtSearch](http://www.dtsearch.com/) have interface that let you index and search with "**semantic search**" or "**Synonym Search**" but also with phonetic and other. dtSearch use the WordNet library.

The dtSearch is very powerfull, give the full engine in one dll, and can search  fuzziness, synonym/concept/thesaurus, boolean, phrase, wildcard, proximity, 
stemming, numeric range, natural language and other...

Can index PDF, Word and most of the known documents direct.

Now if you create your custom indexer you can [download the WordNet](http://wordnet.princeton.edu/wordnet/download/) database and use it.
For each word that your user search, you can find the relative words using the WordNet database and thesaurus.

Comment: Thanks alot , but i want a dll to help me to search semanticlly through my .net application

Comment: @just_name What do you mean to help you search ? The processing of search is done via indexing. For example, you have the word "road" and the indexes says that is located on document id 34,45,50. Now you use the "WordNet" and from the "road" is also have the "route" and the indexer now say that the "route" is located on document id "55". The index make the search, the semantic search is just find the relative words.