# How can I match two strings, one containing "and" the other "&" or "+"?

Tags: c#, string, replace, comparison

I'm comparing two lists of titles to get a third list. In this case the first list is a list of all the albums by an artist, the second is the list of said artist's albums in a library and the third list is the albums missing from the library.

I have code that's working well and copes with missing punctuation and accented characters, but it's failing when it comes to titles that can be either "<word 1> and <word 2>" or "<word 1> & <word 2>" or even "<word 1> + <word 2>".

The easiest solution is to do something like this on all the titles:

```
title = title.Replace(" + ", " and ").Replace(" & ", " and ");
```

so that they're all in the same form. NOTE: I'm checking for the symbols surrounded by spaces to hopefully ensure I get the cases where the symbol means "and".

However, this doesn't strike me as being very efficient, especially for a long list of titles.

Is there a more efficient way of doing the text substitution or, better still, a way of comparing the original strings to get a valid match?

Comment: It seems like you need a tokenizer that allows you to hash and compare tokens.

Comment: @DavidL - that's a very good idea. As with a lot of things like this, if you don't search for the right terms you don't come up with anything useful.

Comment: [Get started with semantic search](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/project/search/get-started-search) • [Semantic search .net library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17051828/) • [Latent semantic analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latent_semantic_analysis) • You can also take a look at programming syntax analysis [techniques](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing).

Answer (score 5):

Answer below mine is better. Use the character class to account for spaces " [+&] ".

You can use RegEx:

- () group the regular expression
- \\+ will match the '+' character
- '|' means or
- & will match the '&' character

```cs
var title = Regex.Replace(title, "(\\+|&)", "and")
```

See it in action here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/9HY1pH

Comment: Don't forget that it needs to match the & and + when surrounded by spaces.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a single Regex.Replace, and match either `+` or `&` using a [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) like  `[+&]`  preceded and followed by a space.

```
string title = "this & that + those";
Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace(title, @" [+&] ", " and "));
```

Output

```
this and that and those
```